# How to include a link_to block within a label_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to use label_tag "Categories" and to include a plus button next to the label, which is a link_to do block that has a span (the plus button).

Answer (score 1):

It is super simple.

```
= label_tag "your label text"
= link_to root_path do
  span your text
```

The above is slim, but ask me if you need haml or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it worked passing a label_tag do block

```
    <%=label_tag do %>
    #link_to do block with a span
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks. Please select as "Answer" if it is ok!